# specifying Azure blob virtual folder instead of file for ingesting into Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Referring to the `.ingest into table <tablename>` feature , as per the documentation we need to specify direct file name (blob). But it is more common that we may have a bunch of text files in a given blob path , all of which need to be imported. Is there a way we can specify path? I have tried specifying but Kusto won't like folder path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kusto does not iterate over folders or containers.

Comment: so we have to provide exact file (blob) name for Kusto to be able to ingest from azure storage?

Comment: You can check out LightIngest tool that is able to ingest from containers / virtual directories - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/lightingest.

Comment: ...or you can use Azure Data Factory

Answer (score 1):

Zip all your files up into a file. Place on blob. This [ingest into] command worked for me:

```
.ingest into table Blah ( 
h@'https://YOURACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/somefolder/FileFullofCsvs.zip;YOURKEY'
) 
with (
format = "csv",
ignoreFirstRecord = true,
zipPattern="*.csv"
)
```

Comment: This absolutely worked fine. I see an option to specify "with (folder = ' ')" any idea ? I tried with no success

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this by creating external table referencing your blob storage folder.

1. Generate SAS token.

Generate SAS token for your blob storage folder. (ensure to select read and list permissions and any other appropriately)

2. Create external table

Here is the Kusto query

```
.create external table myExternalTable(ProductID:string, Name:string ,Description:string, ExpiryDate:datetime)
kind=blob
dataformat=csv
(
  h@'https://{storageaccount}.blob.core.windows.net/{file system}/{folder name}?{SAS token url generated from step1}
)
```

3. Create Table in Azure Data Explorer DB

Set or Append data to Azure Data Explorer database table.

```
.set-or-append myProductTable (extend_schema=true) <|external_table("myExternalTable")
```

4. Query the table

This will list all the data rows in the table

```
myProductTable
```